# How to use the docker connection-plugin of ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible

I want to create and edit docker containers automated using ansible and I found a connection plugin in the ansible GitHub repository, which uses docker exec instead of ssh to run commands etc. inside the container.
I can't find any documentation about this plugin and can't exactly figure out how to use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple: set `connection: docker` and use container names as inventory hosts.

Example:

```
# docker run -d --name=mycontainer -e FOO=bar alpine:latest sleep 600
fde1a28914174c53e8f186f2b8ea312c0bda9c895fc6c956f3f1315788f0bf20
# ansible all -i 'mycontainer,' -c docker -m raw -a 'echo $FOO'
mycontainer | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
bar
```

Just keep in mind, that most of Ansible modules require Python, but usually you have minimal amount of libraries inside your containers, and Python is not among them.

Comment: thank you.
is it possible to connect trough ssh to another computer wich is running docker or does docker-connection only work local on the computer wich has ansible installed?

Comment: AFAIK docker connection plugin is designed to work only with local docker daemon. You can try to play with [DOCKER_HOST](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables) env variable to trick Ansible to work with remote docker host. But I can't think of any way to force this plugin to connect trough ssh tunnel.

Comment: These days it is ```ansible_connection: docker```

Comment: `ansible_connection` – when defined in inventory, `connection` – when used as play's attribute.

Answer (score 3):

## 2020 TLDR: run a minimal Python container

In 2020, the above solution (running a minimal Alpine container) doesn't work --
Python is not installed.

Building on Konstantin Suvorov's answer, to make Ansible happy, give it a slim Python container:

```
docker run -d --name=mycontainer python:3.8-slim-buster sleep 600
```

Check:

```
ansible all -i 'mycontainer,' -c docker -m setup
```

### Classic solution

The solution above no longer works, Python is not discoverable by Ansible:

```
docker run -d --name=bogus alpine:latest sleep 600

ansible all -i 'bogus,' -c docker -m setup

[WARNING]: No python interpreters found for host bogus (tried ['/usr/bin/python',
'python3.7', 'python3.6', 'python3.5', 'python2.7', 'python2.6',
'/usr/libexec/platform-python', '/usr/bin/python3', 'python'])
```

To make Ansible happy, give it a slim Python container:

```
docker run -d --name=mycontainer python:3.8-slim-buster sleep 600
```

Check:

```
ansible all -i 'mycontainer,' -c docker -m setup
```

### Recommended Docker image

Itamar Turner-Trauring[1] recommended base Python image = python:3.8-slim-buster.
The Alpine image, although nice and tiny, causes a lots of problems with Python!
The above image is Debian-based, small enough, and totally solid.

[1] from https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/

Comment: This container's Python wasn't under `/usr/bin`, so either because of that or because of the Ansible version I was running inside an Ubuntu Bionic Vagrant box, I needed to add `-e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python'` to the Ansible command (which would normally go in the inventory).